# How to Handle textbox values on sever side

Tags: c#-4.0

I have three `textboxes`.
In textbox1 and in textbox2 i entered a number Like ->

```
Textbox1-0123456789
Textbox2-0123-456-789
Textboxe3-0123-456-789
```

Now on server side i.e on `aspx.cs` page i need to check the numbers is it same or not and only one distinct number will be saved in database

Comment: Just remove the '-' and compare those string.

Comment: What exactly you want? you want how to access textbox value at server side or you want logic for how to compare textbox values?

Answer (score 0):

//Get the values from text box and form a list
//validate against a regular expression to make them pure numeric
//now check if they are all same

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>()
                { 
                 "0123-456-A789",
                 "0123-456-A789",
                "0123-456-789"
                };

                Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
                //s1 = rgx.Replace(s1, "");

                for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                {
                    var value = lst[i];
                    value = rgx.Replace(value, "");

                    lst[i] = value;
                }

                if (lst.Any(num => num != lst[0]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All are not same");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All are same");
                }
```

//if all are same, pick an entry from the list
// if not throw error

HOPE THIS MAY GIVE U  AN IDEA !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If we apply replace("-","") than from every textbox it will remove dash.The number which is same like in
textbox1-0123456789
textbox2=0123-456-789 
textbox3=678-908-999

than replace will remove dash from textbox3 also which we dont want.
so For this we have to apply not exists operation of linq.

List strMobileNos = new List();

Regex re = new Regex(@"\d{10}|\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4}");
!strMobileNos.Exists(l => l.Replace("-", "") == Request.Form["txtMobNo2"].Replace("Mobile2", "").Replace("-", ""))